# Theorem 9, Section 3.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, independence

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over the field $F$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(W)$. If $T$ is linear transformation from $V$ into $W$, the following are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$ $T$ is invertible.
>
> $(2)$ $T$ is non-singular.
>
> $(3)$ $T$ is onto, that is, the range of $T$ is $W$.
>
> $(4)$ If $\{\alpha_1,..\alpha_n\}$ is basis for $V$, then $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis for $W$.
>
> $(5)$ There is some basis $\{\alpha_1,…\alpha_n\}$ for $V$ such that $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Now there are lots of way to prove this theorem, like $(1)\Rightarrow (2)\Rightarrow (3) \Rightarrow (4)\Rightarrow (5)\Rightarrow (1)$, I think this is the least number of implication needed to prove this theorem. I want to prove this theorem by first showing $(1)$, $(2)$ & $(3)$ are equivalent, then show $(1) \Leftrightarrow (4)\Leftrightarrow (5)$.

---

**$(1)$, $(2)$ & $(3)$ are equivalent**. You would agree proof of $(2)\Leftrightarrow (3)$ is essentially same as proof of $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)$, $(1) \Leftrightarrow (3)$. **My attempt:** $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$. Suppose $T$ is non-singular. Then $N_T=\{0_V\}$. So $\mathrm{dim}(N_T)=0$. By rank nullity theorem, $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(N_T)+ \mathrm{dim}(R_T)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(R_T)$. By assumption, $\mathrm{dim}(V)= \mathrm{dim}(R_T)= \mathrm{dim}(W)$. $R_T\leq W$ and $W$ is finite-dimensional vector space. By contrapositive of theorem 5 corollary 1 section 2.3, $R_T=W$. Hence $T$ is surjective. $(2)\Leftarrow (3)$. Suppose $T$ is surjective. Then $R_T=W$. So $\mathrm{dim}(R_T)= \mathrm{dim}(W)$. By rank nullity theorem, $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(N_T)+ \mathrm{dim}(R_T)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(N_T)+ \mathrm{dim}(W)$. By assumption, $\mathrm{dim}(V)= \mathrm{dim}(N_T)+ \mathrm{dim}(W)= \mathrm{dim}(W)$. So $\mathrm{dim}(N_T)=0$. It’s easy to check, $\mathrm{dim}(N_T)=0$$\iff$$N_T=\{0_V\}$. Hence $T$ is injective. **Is my proof correct?** Proof is basically corollary of rank nullity theorem.

---

**$(1)$, $(4)$ & $(5)$ are equivalent**. $(1)\Rightarrow (4)$. Suppose $T$ is invertible/bijective. **Approach(1):** Let $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$be a basis of $V$. Since $T$ is injective and $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is independent, we have $T(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\})=\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is independent, by theorem 8 section 3.2. Since $T$ is injective, we have $T(\alpha_i)\neq T(\alpha_j)$, if $i\neq j$. So $|\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}|$ $=n=\mathrm{dim}(W)$. By theorem 4 corollary 2 section 2.3, $\mathrm{span}(T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n))=W$. Hence $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis of $W$. Alternative way to show $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ span $W$, using full strength of $(1)$. Let $w\in W$. Since $T$ is surjective, $\exists v\in V$ such that $T(v)=w$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)=V$, we have $v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot_V \alpha_i$. So $T(v)=T(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$. Thus $T(v)=w\in \mathrm{span}(T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n))$. Hence $\mathrm{span}(T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n))=W$. So $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis of $W$. **Approach(2):** One can do same thing in reverse order, i.e first prove $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis, only using $T$ is surjective. Alternative way to show $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is independent, use full strength of $(1)$, mainly $T$ is injective.

$(1)\Leftarrow (4)$. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space with $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have $\exists \{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}\subseteq V$ basis of $V$. By hypothesis, $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis of $W$. If $T(x)=T(y)$, for some $x,y\in V$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)=V$, we have $x=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$ and $y=\sum_{i\in J_n}b_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. So $T(x)=T(y)$ $=T(\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_V)$ $=T(\sum_{i\in J_n}b_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}b_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$. Since $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is independent, we have $a_i-b_i=0_F$, $\forall i\in J_n$. So $a_i=b_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $x=y$. Hence $T$ is injective. Let $w\in W$. Since $\mathrm{span}(T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n))=W$, we have $w=\sum_{i\in J_n} c_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$ $=T(\sum_{i\in J_n} c_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$. Thus $w\in R_T$. Hence $R_T=W$, i.e. $T$ is surjective. So $T$ is bijective. **Is my proof correct?**

$(4)\Rightarrow (5)$ Since $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space with $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have $\exists \{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}\subseteq V$ basis of $V$. By hypothesis, $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis of $W$.

$(4)\Leftarrow (5)$. Suppose $\exists  \{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\} \subseteq V$ basis of $V$ such that $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is basis of $W$. **Approach(1):** Let $\{\beta_1,…,\beta_n\}$ be basis of $V$. So $\alpha_j=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\cdot_V \beta_i$. Let $w\in W$. Since $\mathrm{span}(T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n))=W$, we have $w=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_W T(\alpha_j)$ $=T(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \alpha_j)$. By theorem 7 section 2.4, $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \alpha_j$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c_j)\cdot_V \beta_i$. So $w= T(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \alpha_j)$ $=T(\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c_j)\cdot_V \beta_i)$. By linearity of $T$, $w=T(\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c_j)\cdot_V \beta_i)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c_j)\cdot_W T(\beta_i)$. Thus $w\in \mathrm{span}(T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n))$. Hence $\mathrm{span}(T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n))=W$. We claim  $T(\beta_i)\neq T(\beta_j)$, if $i\neq j$. Assume towards contradiction, $\exists p,q\in J_n$ such that $p\neq q$ and $T(\beta_p)=T(\beta_q)$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)=V$, we have $\beta_p=\sum_{i\in J_n}r_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$ and $\beta_q=\sum_{i\in J_n}s_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. So $T(\beta_p)$ $=T(\beta_q)$ $=T(\sum_{i\in J_n}r_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=T(\sum_{i\in J_n}s_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}r_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}s_i\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$. Since $\{T(\alpha_1),…T(\alpha_n)\}$ is independent, we have $r_i=s_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. So $\beta_p=\beta_q$. Thus we reach contradiction. So $|\{T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n)\}|$ $=n=\mathrm{dim}(W)$. By theorem 4 corollary 2 section 2.3, $\{T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n)\}$ is independent. Hence $\{T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n)\}$ is basis of $W$. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** Let $\{\beta_1,…,\beta_n\}$ be basis of $V$. We need to show $\{T(\beta_1),…,T(\beta_n)\}$ is independent. If $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_W T(\beta_j)=0_W$. Since $T$ is a linear map, we have $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_W T(\beta_j)$ $=T(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \beta_j)$ $=0_W$. Since $\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)=V$, we have $\beta_j=\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}\cdot_V \alpha_i$, $\forall j\in J_n$. By theorem 7 section 2.4, $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \beta_j$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} c_j)\cdot_V \alpha_i$. So $T(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot_V \beta_j)$ $=T(\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} c_j)\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} c_j)\cdot_W T(\alpha_i)$ $=0_W$. Since $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is independent, $\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} c_j=0_F$, $\forall i\in J_n$. The thing is that, I don’t known anything about matrix theory. So I can’t make progress. **Can you please help me?**

Comment: if you don't know the definition of invertible, then you should look that up first of all even before trying to prove anything. Also, I doubt Hoffman and Kunze would introduce material without having covered the necessary prerequisites, so if you're having trouble with that, then you should probably review the earlier parts of the text.