# Exercise 7, Section 3.7 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism, transpose

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$. Show that $T \to T^t$ is an isomorphism of $L(V, V)$ onto $L(V^*, V^*)$.

> Note: For $T\in L(V, W) $ , the dual map (or transpose) $T^t\in
>  L(W^{\star}, V^{\star})$ is defined by $$(T^tg) (\alpha) =g(T\alpha) $$
> for every $g\in W^{\star}$ and $\alpha\in V$

We already known $L(V,V)\cong L(V^*,V^*)$, since $\mathrm{dim}(L(V,V))$ $=(\mathrm{dim}(V))^2$ $= (\mathrm{dim}(V^*))^2$ $= \mathrm{dim}(L(V^*,V^*))$. In this problem, we are being asked to show $f:L(V,V)\to L(V^*,V^*)$ defined by $f(T)=T^t$ is isomorphism.

**My attempt:** Let $T,L\in L(V,V)$ and $c\in F$. Then $f(c\cdot T+L)$ $=(c\cdot T+L)^t$. So $[(c\cdot T+L)^t](g)$ $=g\circ (c\cdot T+L)$ $=c\cdot (g\circ T)+g\circ L$ $=c\cdot T^t(g)+L^t(g)$ $=(c\cdot T^t+L^t)(g)$, $\forall g\in V^*$. Thus $(c\cdot T+L)^t$ $=c\cdot T^t+L^t$ $=c\cdot f(T)+f(L)$. Hence $f$ is an linear map.

Now we show $f$ is bijective. Since $\mathrm{dim}(L(V,V))$ $= \mathrm{dim}(L(V^*,V^*))$, it’s suffice to show either $f$ is injective or surjective, by [theorem 9 section 3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489586/861687). If $f(T)=f(L)$, for some $T,L\in L(V,V)$. Then $T^t=L^t$, i.e. $T^t(g)$ $=L^t(g)$ $=g\circ T$ $=g\circ L$, $\forall g\in V^*$. If we can find an injective map $g\in V^*$$=L(V,F)$, then we’re done. I tried following linear functional on $V$, $g(\alpha_j)=1_F$, where $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$. But that isn’t working. Another way to show injective, $N_f=\{0\}$. Let $T\in N_f$. Then $f(T)$ $=T^t$ $=0$, i.e. $T^t(g)$ $=0(g)$ $=g\circ T$ $=0$, $\forall g\in V^*$. Again I’m running into same problem. We have to find an injective map $g\in L(V,F)$ so that $g(T(\alpha))=0$$\implies$$T(\alpha)=0$, $\forall \alpha \in V$. I think showing surjectivity is even more difficult than injective. We are literally working in inception of inception of maps. **How to progress from here?**

Comment: Without the book to look at the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nobody has the definitions from this book to refer to so if you ask this question without the definitions people have to decipher what you mean from reading your proof.

Comment: I've answered your questions about this book before, but I had to do it by going and looking at the text. You'd get better answers if you didn't force people to do that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh In a post, there are multiple way to write same thing. So writing $L(V,V)$ as $L(V)$ don’t change **anything**. What can you conclude $T^t$, from context? You said I didn’t define $T^t$. What? See first paragraph of my attempt. Either you didn’t read the post or you want “explicit” definition.  Nothing in this world is “universal accepted notation”.

Comment: As I have asked earlier, what is the definition of $T^t$? $\\$ For $T\in L(V, W) $ , $\exists ! S\in L(W^{\star}, V^{\star}) $ such that $(Sg)(\alpha)) =g(S \alpha) $ . The unique linear map $g$ is called dual map/ transpose of $T$ and denoted by $T^t$ .

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes….. How to show uniqueness?

Comment: Do not edit your post to include meta content, especially if that content is intended to attack other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy since after identifying $V^{**} = V$, we have $(T^t)^t = T$. The identification $V \approx V^{**}$ identifies $v \in V$ with the map $\omega \mapsto \langle v, \omega \rangle_{V, V^*}$. It may seem like this identification is only an inclusion, but surjectivity follows since $V$ and $V^{**}$ are both $n$-dimensional.

Edit: $(T^t)^t = T$ because for $v' \in V^*$ and $v \in V^{**} = V$, $$\langle T^t v', v \rangle = \langle v, T^t v'\rangle = \langle Tv, v' \rangle = \langle v', Tv\rangle.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How $(T^t)^t=T$? What $\langle v, \omega \rangle_{V, V^*}$ represent? I know one isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$, for each $\alpha \in V$, define $L_\alpha: V^*\to F$ such that $L_\alpha (g)=g(\alpha)$, $\forall g\in V^*$.

Comment: @user264745 I use $\langle v, \omega \rangle_{V, V^*} := \omega(v)$. Your isomorphism is the same one I described.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer?

Comment: @user264745 I added the full details. It's really just applying the definition of $t$.

Comment: You’re over complicating. I’m assuming your answer is correct. Can you show using my approach, simply using definition of injective map? Read last paragraph of my post. You will understand what I’m asking. Did you downvote my post? If yes, then it seems you did it out of frustration. I’m pretty sure you haven’t read complete post properly maybe because of length of post.

Comment: @user264745 Realize that I have shown that $t : L(V) \to L(V^*)$ has inverse $t^{-1} = t : L(V^*) \to L(V^{**}) = L(V).$ Existence of an inverse map is equivalent to bijectivity.

Comment: @user264745 I didn't downvote your post. If I thought it was a bad question, I wouldn't have answered it.

Comment: ohh.. you’re using different characterization of bijection. Can you give feedback on my approach? Where I’m getting wrong?

Comment: Your approach isn't wrong, you just haven't finished the proof. You want to show that if $T^t = 0$, then $T = 0$. So we have $\langle Tv, v' \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$ and $v' \in V^*$, and we want to show that $T = 0$. But this says that $Tv = 0$ as an element of $V^{**}$, for all $v \in V$. Since the inclusion $V \to V^{**}$ is injective (in fact, it preserves norms), this shows that $Tv = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: I don’t understand following statement: But this says that $T(v)=0$ as an element of $V^{**}$, for all $v\in V$. I’m sorry for not understanding things.