# Exercise $5$, Section $6.A$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products

Exercise: Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $T\in L(V)$ is such that $\|Tv\|\le \|v\|$ for every $v\in V$. Prove that $T-\sqrt{2}I$ is invertible.

Proof: We will prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $T-\sqrt 2I$ is not invertible. Thus, $\sqrt 2$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Tv=\sqrt{2}v$. Taking the norm on both sides and dividing by $\|v\|$ we get $\frac {\|Tv\|} {\|v\|}=\sqrt 2$. Because $\sqrt 2>1$, the above equality implies that $\|Tv\|>\|v\|$ as if $0\le a < b$, then $\frac a b<1$.

Is this proof correct? Is there a better way to prove this?

Edit: For any future readers, the proof above could be better phrased and there is no need to bring up eigenvalues(although $\sqrt 2$ will still be an eigenvalue). I never explicitly state where I use the hypothesis that $V$ is finite dimensional. The following is what I would write as a proof now.

Proof: We will prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $T-\sqrt 2I$ is not invertible. Because $V$ is finite dimensional, injectivity implies invertibility. Thus, $T-\sqrt 2I$ is not injective and there exists a non-zero vector $v\in null(T-\sqrt 2I)$ such that $(T-\sqrt 2I)v=0\implies Tv=\sqrt 2v$. Taking the norm on both sides and dividing by $\|v\|$ we get $\frac {\|Tv\|} {\|v\|}=\sqrt 2$. Because $\sqrt 2>1$, the previous equality implies that $\|Tv\|>\|v\|$ as if $0\le a < b$, then $\frac a b < 1$.

Comment: What is $V$ and what is the norm on $V$?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Just a comment: this proof only works if $V$ is finite-dimensional. If $\text{dim }V=\infty$ and $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $V$, with $\|Tv\|\leq \|v\|$ for all $v$, then the same conclusion holds.

Comment: @geetha290krm There was no specific norm specified. $V$ is taken to be an inner product space.

Comment: Your proof is fine as long as $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the comments. I did somehow  not write the assumption that $V$ is supposed to finite dimensional.

Comment: @Feng Thanks. I did forget to write the assumption that $V$ is supposed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: @geetha290krm But I am confused about one part. I can’t see where I used the hypothesis that $V$ is finite dimensional. As I didn’t read that $V$ was supposed to be finite dimensional at first and started reading the main part. That was a stupid thing to do.

Comment: If $V$ is an  infinite dimensional normed linear space you cannot say that $\sqrt2$ is an eigen value.

Comment: @geetha290krm I am not too much familiar with infinite dimensional vector spaces. Could you please explain why $\sqrt 2$ can’t be an eigenvalue?Isn’t the fact that $T-\sqrt 2 I$ not invertible implies that $\sqrt 2$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Because if $T-\sqrt 2I$ is not invertible, there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $(T-\sqrt 2)v=0$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh never mind. I just realised that $T-\sqrt 2I$ not being invertible doesn’t imply that $T-\sqrt 2I$ is not injective in infinite dimensions.

Comment: Equivalent definition of eigenvalue: $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$$\iff$ker$(T-\lambda I)\neq 0$$\iff$$T$ is not injective$\iff$$T$ is not invertible$\iff$det$(T-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: @user264745 It is true that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $T$ is not injective and therefore not invertible. But this only holds on finite dimensional vector spaces. This is not true for infinite dimensional vector spaces. Consider the infinite dimensional vector space $P(\Bbb{R})$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{R}$. Define an operator $T : P(\Bbb{R})\to P(\Bbb{R})$ by $Tp=x^2p$. This operator is injective, but it is not surjective and therefore not invertible.

Comment: @user264745 In infinite dimensions, injectivity or surjectiviy alone doesn't imply invertibility. They both have to hold for an operator to be invertible.

Comment: @user264745 It is also not true that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T\iff T$ is not injective. Consider the identity operator $I : V\to V$. Clearly $1$ is an eigenvalue of $I$ and $I$ is injective. It is however true that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T\iff T-\lambda I$ is not injective. And therefore not invertible.

Comment: @user264745 For an example of an operator that is surjective but not injective, consider the backward shift operator $T : F^\infty \to F^\infty$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,\dots )=(x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Here $F^\infty$ denotes the infinite dimensional vector space of all sequences of elements of $F$. Thus, $F=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots ) : x_j\in F\text{ for }j=1,\dots \}$. Note that this operator is surjective but is is not injective. And therefore not invertible. This is because $T(1, 0, 0, \dots )=T(2, 0, 0, \dots)$ but $(1, 0, 0, \dots)\ne (2, 0, 0, \dots)$.

Comment: @Seeker yeah. $T:V\to V$ is an linear operator on finite dimensional vector space. In linear algebra, we mostly study about finite dimensional vector space. Yes I meant to write $T-\lambda I$, not $T$. Which is “obvious” from context. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489586/861687) is details of relation between bijectivity, injectivity and surjectivity, on a finite dimensional vector space. You have constructed lots of counter example, which is nice but those things you may have proved in past.